# Button is always set to disabled

Tags: java, android

What I want to do is disable those buttons If `Boolean` num10, num11 and so on are set to `true`. But when I open the `SecondActivity`, it always shows disabled buttons. Even If I didn't pressed the button.

What should I do?

This is my code:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buyItem1,buyItem2,buyItem3,buyItem4;
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences2;
    boolean num10 = false, num11 = false, num12 = false, num13 = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mySharedPreferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final int goldamountval = intent.getIntExtra("parameter1", 0);
        TextView goldamount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.goldamount);
        goldamount.setText("" + goldamountval);
        buyItem1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyitem1);
        buyItem2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyitem2);
        buyItem3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyitem3);
        buyItem4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyitem4);
        buyItem1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(goldamountval >= 1000){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences2.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(String.valueOf(num10), true);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });

        buyItem2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(goldamountval >= 5000){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences2.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(String.valueOf(num11), true);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });

        buyItem3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(goldamountval >= 10000){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences2.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(String.valueOf(num12), true);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });

        buyItem4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(goldamountval >= 50000){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences2.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(String.valueOf(num13), true);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });
        if (num10 = true){
            buyItem1.setEnabled(false);
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.item4);
            button.setText("Drill");
        }
        if (num11 = true){
            buyItem2.setEnabled(false);
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.item5);
            button.setText("Excavator");
        }
        if (num12 = true){
            buyItem3.setEnabled(false);
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.item6);
            button.setText("Digger");
        }
        if (num13 = true){
            buyItem4.setEnabled(false);
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.item7);
            button.setText("Mine Permission");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `if` you assign the boolean (`if (num10 = true)`) so they are always `true` and than every button is disabled. You need to change the code like this one:

```
if (num10 == true){
    buyItem1.setEnabled(false);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.item4);
    button.setText("Drill");
}
if (num11 == true){
    buyItem2.setEnabled(false);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.item5);
    button.setText("Excavator");
}
if (num12 == true){
    buyItem3.setEnabled(false);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.item6);
    button.setText("Digger");
}
if (num13 == true){
    buyItem4.setEnabled(false);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.item7);
    button.setText("Mine Permission");
}
```

Comment: :D I forgot that, Thank you!

Comment: Could just say `if (num10)`